# having trouble understanding the use of write_fds in select() - c

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a server that has the ability to receive and send msgs to clients.
I'm using `select()` to keep track of all connected clients.

`select(max_fd+1,&read_fd,&write_fd,NULL,NULL);`

I do understand the use of the `read_fds` in select - if some client sends me data or trying to connect to the server, select will wake up, and the read_fd will contain all the fd's that I can read data from them.
however, I'm having trouble understanding the use of the write_fds:
I don't see how and when select will wake up because of a change in write_fd in the server program (and thus I think I don't need to use it).

I will thank everyone who will clarify the use of write_fd. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, when you send a response to client, there may be a situation when it
does not able yet to receive more data (bandwidth/response time and so on).

In such cases write operation may block.

Thus you need to check for "writability" of the socket before you write into it.

Note if you use nonblocking sockets you should use it only when you receive EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK error on write operation, when using blocking sockets you should
always make sure that the socket is writeable (using write_fds) before you send the data.

Answer (score 1):

When using TCP sockets any data sent must be stored in the socket cache until the remote end has confirmed that it has received the data (by ACKing the data). If you are sending data faster than the remote end is consuming the data, you will eventually fill the buffer. At this point, if you are using a blocking socket, the send will block until the data can be placed in the buffer. At this point, the socket (file descriptor) is not writable and the select will block until the buffer has space available for writing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use non-blocking sockets, the write set will tell you when a socket is ready to send more data.

Answer (score 0):

All of this complex, confusing sockets business is explained very clearly and completely in the book:

W. Richard Stevens, Bill Fenner, and Andrew M. Rudoff,  **[Unix Network Programming, Volume 1: The Sockets Networking API (3rd Edition)](http://tinyurl.com/3mvggvb)**

If you can find a copy in the library, you'll have the complete info right in front of you. Moreover, there will be sample code that probably follows very closely the code you're trying to understand.

HTH